# GridView not scrolling to bottom proberly

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I have an issue with my GridView. It is not scrolling to the bottom of the GridView proberly. I have used the GridView from the [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) site. Here is how the bottom of my screen looks like when I scroll all the way down: [image]
So it is cutting off the bottom of the last two grids. However I have solved this by adding padding to the bottom of my GridView that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="55dp"
    />
```

The problem is that the padding of 55dp fits perfectly to my Samsung Galaxy S5. But i suspect this is not the case for other devices? And if I add more padding I will get a permanent white line at the bottom of the screen even though the GridView is not scrolled all the way down.

Here is my class for implementing the GridView:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my GridViewAdapter class:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(screenWidth/2, screenWidth/2));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.cat,
            R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.bunny,
            R.drawable.fish, R.drawable.hamster,
            R.drawable.hedgehog, R.drawable.bird
    };
}
```

So my question in short is: Is there a way to ensure the GridView will fit the screen perfectly without having to add the padding to the bottom of the GridView, which I suppose won't be the same padding for all devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an SDK higher than 20, you can use

```
int yourNavigationBarHeight;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if(resourceId > 0)
    yourNavigationBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
else 
    yourNavigationBarHeight = 0;
```